# How to select few text lines using Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I am writing an automation test script using Robot Framework & Selenium2Library for testing our web application ( in `.txt` format ).

One of my test cases involves to select few lines of text from web page, following with this text selection, some text formatting options will render in page to modify the style of that particular selected text ( Please refer the following image ).

[image]

[image]

**1** ) Is there any specific keyword in Robot Framework to select few text or few lines of text from a webpage ?

Along with that, can I store the selected text field into a variable ?

Here is the HTML code of the particular section :

```
<div>
     I am writing an automation test script using Robot Framework & Selenium2Library for testing our web application(in '.txt' format).
</div>
```

If I Select bold from the text formatting options, html code will change like this :

```
<div>
     I am writing an <b> automation test script </b> using Robot Framework & Selenium2Library for testing our web application(in '.txt' format).
</div>
```

**2** ) Is there any method in Robot Framework to store the text field's inside an html tag into a variable ?

Here, How can I store the text field's inside `html` tag `<b>` into a variable ? [ But id's will not be there ! ]

Comment: did you try regex? you can give pattern you are looking for and save the output to variable.